# How to implement code grant flow in REST API?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, django-authentication, django-oauth

I am developing web application in React and Django(Rest Framework)., i want to users can login with `google account`.,

I approach i followed is `implicit grant flow`.,where i get the `access token` in the front end., and sent the access token to the back-end. then the back-end should verify the access token with `google`., and return the new `jwt token` for future requests. once the user logged out.,  same cycle continues.,

By My client don't want repeat the same `implicit grant flow` for other devices(mobile for example)., they want `authentication` to be handled entirely by back-end. so i am planning to use `code exchange flow`.

the approach i am planning.

1. user clicks the login with google button
2. send the request to django back-end, get the clientId and server callback URL.
3. client redirect the request to google with the client id and `callback url`.
4. google ask permission to users and sends the access token to backend.

In the above approach the connection between client and server is broke in step 3., how to we know the back-end got the access-token. user logged in?

Comment: Unclear what is the issue.

Comment: once react send the request to `google`  with scope i need., google will prompt the user for necessary permission and send the code/access_token to our `django-server`.,  now how does react know server got `access_token`. i hope i made my point